# "if" and "else if" conditions both are executed with in the filter function( Angular-8, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angular

"if" and "else if" conditions both are executed with in the filter function. when i tried to execute below program i'm getting output as

[image]

```js
 this.users.filter((hero)=> {
     if(hero.name === this.profileForm.value.name && hero.password === this.profileForm.value.password){
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      console.log("in if")
     }else if(hero.name !== this.profileForm.value.name){
      console.log("in else if")
     this.isValid=false;
     }
```

Could any one help me what is the issue with code.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  CanActivate, Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot
}                           from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private router:Router) { }


  ngOnInit() {
  }
isValid:boolean=true;
  users =[{
    name:"user1",
    password:"password1"
  },
{
  name:"user2",
  password:"password2"
}
]

  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    password: new FormControl('',[Validators.minLength(6),Validators.required]),
  });
  
onSubmit(){
  
  this.users.filter((hero)=> {
     if(hero.name === this.profileForm.value.name && hero.password === this.profileForm.value.password){
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      console.log("in if")
     }else if(hero.name !== this.profileForm.value.name){
      console.log("in else if")
     this.isValid=false;
     }
    
  }); 
 
  
}

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="login-page">
        <h2 >Welcome to Timesheet Tracker</h2>
        <div class="form">
          
          <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      
            <input type="text" placeholder="username"  formControlName="name"/>
            <span *ngIf="!profileForm.get('name').valid && profileForm.get('name').touched" class="help-block">Please enter user name..!</span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" formControlName="password"/>
            <span *ngIf="!profileForm.get('password').valid && profileForm.get('password').touched" class="help-block">Please enter valid password..!</span>
            <button type="submit" >login</button>
            
          </form>
          <p class="par" *ngIf="!isValid">Please enter valid user name and password..!</p>
        </div>
       
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The array `users` has two elements. One satisfies `if` condition and the other satisfies `else if`. That's why you see both printed.

Comment: Why are you doing `router.navigate()` within a `filter()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `.filter` here. `.filter` iterates for each value. For some values, one condition is met, for others the other condition and hence both `if` and `else` seem to be getting executed.

What you need to do is something like this:

```
 let heroFound = false;

  for(let hero of this.users){
   if(hero.name === this.profileForm.value.name && hero.password === 
  this.profileForm.value.password){
       heroFound = true;
       break;

    }

  }

  if(heroFound){
   this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }else{
    this.isValid=false;
  }
```